# Display fragment without transition

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-scrollview, android-transitions, fragmentmanager

I have a fragment inside a scroll view.

When the fragment is loaded, the scroll view scrolls down to the fragment.

I want to load the fragment into the scroll view, but I don't want the scroll view to scroll down to the fragment from it's current position(top), when it is loaded.

This is how I load the fragment :

```
  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

  FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

  ft.add(bikeFragContainer.getId(),bikeFrag);
  ft.show(bikeFrag);
  ft.commit();

  setBikeFragData();
```

The reason for the scroll seems to me, is that, `ft.commit()` loads the fragment and moves the screen to display the fragment.

Is there any way to load the fragment into the scroll view, without moving the scroll view to the fragment, when it is loaded into the scroll view?

I think the answer lies in finding a way to tell the `FragmentManager` or `FragmentTransaction` to, just load the fragment but not do any transition.  Any suggestion guys ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite your help, I couldn't find a clean solution for my issue.

The reason is that, my approach might not be the right (to include a fragment in a scrollview and expect it not to scroll) and there might be better approaches.

What I did is to fix my issue is, I forced the scroll view, to scroll to the top, right after the fragment is loaded. So the user sees the scroll view scrolling down and up once very fast.(I know clumsy!)

Here is my code :

```
 android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        ft.add(mGridContainer.getId(),bikeFrag);
        ft.commit();
        setBikeFrag();


        scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);   // scrolls to top of scrollview  
            }
        }, 1000);
```

I wait one second after fragment transaction takes place and scroll to the top.

May be this delay can be reduced , but I kept it as one second, just to be safe.

`scrollView`  is the object of the ScrollView widget, in my layout.

It is inside this scroll view, the fragment, along with some other widgets are located.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by `android:textIsSelectable`. You may try adding the following to the `ScrollView`:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. I believe the scrolling happens when I call  `ft.commit()` . I have edited the question, please have a look.

Comment: Have you tried out fragmentTransaction.setTransition(TRANSIT_UNSET);  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setTransition(int)

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't solve the issue! I tried `fragmentTransaction.setTransition(TRANSIT_UNSET); ` and other things  on the link you provided, but none of them works.                         I also tried setting a custom animation file(which is an empty xml file) to prevent the transaction, but it didn't work.                                                 I suppose, there is no way to prevent the fragment taking up focus automatically, when fragment is loaded.